# Twilio how to connect two numbers but allow one to hang up and then come back

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I want to call #1 and once they answer call #2. This is easy enough using `<Dial>`. However I want to let #1 then hang up while keeping #2 on the line and then I want to be able to add #1 back into the call later. Do I need a conference for this? I don't want any hold music or for it to feel like a conference room. If so, how do I get both parties into the conference in a single TwiML response?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a conference using the [Conference Participant](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource) resource. To avoid the hold music, you can set the [WaitUrl to empty](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-waitUrl), or you could add a third call.

For the third call scenario, place Call #1 as you described, then for Call #2 place a call with a "Say" that could include something like "adding the caller." When Call #2 joins the conference the Twilio hold music will stop. Then you can place Call #3 to add the real caller.

I can't think of how you could do this with one Twiml command. You will need to listen to the [Conference Status Callback webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent) for participants joining inorder to add Call #3.